# cxf vs axis (big xml over soap)

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, apache-axis, axis

I have a concern regarding handling big xml's over SOAP. 
In Axis it is written that,
Axis is essentially Apache SOAP 3.0. It is a from-scratch rewrite, designed around a streaming model (using SAX internally rather than DOM). The intention is to create a more modular, more flexible, and higher-performing SOAP implementation (relative to Apache SOAP 2.0).
http://axis.apache.org/axis/faq.html

Can you tell me how cxf handles SOAPMessages internally. Does it use SAX rather than DOM. If not I think for BI XML's AXIS will be a better choice then..?

Secondly, I see that javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart  implements Document, Node. Does it mean no matter what for a SOAP implementation DOM will always be created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At this point, there is almost nothing that Axis2 can do that CXF cannot do just as well or better.   CXF also uses StAX internally for processing the incoming messages.

That said, you mention SOAPPart.   Those are SAAJ things.   If you drop town to using SAAJ model for processing, then streaming is broken as the SAAJ model requires the entire thing to be pulled into memory.   For the most part CXF, tries hard to avoid SAAJ unless it's required (JAX-WS handlers require it, WS-Security currently requires it).

Comment: Thanks. So if I pull SOAPEnvelope at any point that will create entire tree in memory otherwise not?